# If response text recieved from IBM Domino lotusscript agent has an ‘€’ symbol then it's displaying &#8364

Tags: javascript, web, character, lotusscript, agent

The response text have other chracters link ä which is displaying properly, only Euro (€)chracter is not displaying.
I have used Print |Content-Type:text/plain| . If I include charset=utf-8 then the ä & € chracters are displying ¤ and â‚¬  respectively

Can someone assist me here

Comment: https://www.codetable.net/decimal/8364

Comment: Try charset=ISO-8859-1 - does that work?

Comment: Probably because it's JSON, as JSON converts all these.

Comment: charset=ISO-8859-1 is not working, it's not JSON either. Klaus Gütter not sure what is thet mean.. If I use innerHTML then euro symbol is printing properly.

Comment: Print "<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"" />"

Comment: 8364 is the UTF-16 value for the Euro symbol, not the UTF-8 value.